# Why isn't screen on macOS picking up my ~/.terminfo?

Tags: osx, gnu-screen, terminfo

I'd like to get [Terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) for my terminal (rxvt-unicode) working, so that when I ssh from Linux to macOS, the Home/End and other keys work properly.

Usually, to accomplish this with a Linux remote host, I use a script like the following:

```
ssh "$1" 'mkdir -p ~/.terminfo/r'
for f in /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode{,-256color}
do
    scp "$f" "$1":.terminfo/r/
done
```

However, this isn't working with macOS.

When I run `screen`, first I was getting "TERM too long - sorry.".

After updating it to the brew version (4.06.02), I'm now getting "Cannot find terminfo entry for 'rxvt-unicode-256color'."

`TERM` is correctly set to `rxvt-unicode-256color`, and `~/.terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode-256color` exists.

Running `screen` with `TERMINFO=$HOME/.terminfo/` also has no effect.

Comment: check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345675/screen-cannot-find-terminfo-entry-for-xterm-256color

Comment: Thanks, however that question is for accessing a Linux remote host from a macOS local host. The situation here is the opposite. Also, setting `TERM` is an ugly hack that is likely to cause problems elsewhere - the correct thing to do is to tell the remote applications how to talk to your terminal using a termcap or terminfo file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ncurses uses [2-characters](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html#h3-Mixed-case-terminal-names) for filesystems (such as MacOS and OS/2) where filenames are *case-preserving* / *case-insensitive*.  That is documented in the [**`NEWS`** file](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20071117).  Apple, by the way, provides an old version of ncurses (5.7) which is still new enough for this feature.

Portable applications should not rely upon any particular organization of the terminal database...

By the way, current terminfo entries for xterm-256color will not work well with that old ncurses 5.7 base system, since the color pairs value exceeds limits.  The effect upon rxvt-unicode depends on how the source was constructed. This is mentioned in the [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#compatible_tic):

> [ncurses 6.1](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.1.html#h4-config-major) introduced support for large number capabilities, e.g., for more than 32767 color pairs. Other implementations generally treated out-of-range values as zero.

Comment: The case insensitive thing makes sense, but I don't understand your comment about not relying on the terminfo db. The only thing which relies on the organization of the terminfo db is terminfo itself. Applications don't directly interact with it but interact with the terminfo library. Thus any application, portable or not, doesn't rely upon the organization.

Comment: "Portable applications should not rely upon any particular organization of the terminal database..." Does that mean there is a more canonical way to copy over the terminfo files than creating the directory structure by hand?

Comment: sure - use `infocmp` for dumping entries, `tic` for compiling.

Comment: So, IIUC, the correct procedure would be: 1) acquire the source of the terminfo entry, or decompile it using `infocmp`; 2) copy the source to the target machine; 3) create `~/.terminfo/` on the target machine; 4) compile and install it using `tic`, which should then do the right thing.

Comment: That sounds right ([ncurses FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#big_terminfo) has a more complicated example).

Answer (score 7):

Running `screen` through `dtruss` (like `strace` for macOS) revealed the following:

```
2131/0x12997:  access("/Users/vladimir/.terminfo/72/rxvt-unicode-256color\0", 0x4, 0x7FFF5F2B56EC)       = -1 Err#2
```

For whatever reason, `screen` is using the hexadecimal representation of the first letter instead of simply the first letter for fanning out the `terminfo` directory struture.

So, to fix it, I had to run:

```
ln -s r ~/.terminfo/72
```

Everything seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

On your linux computer, decompile the terminfo with `infocmp` which is often packaged with the `ncurses` package, and save to a temporary file. You can then SCP this file to your mac.

```
$ infocmp rxvt-unicode-256color > tmpterminfo
```

Then on your mac, use the `tic` command to compile the file and it will also place the output in the right place in your home directory:

```
$ tic tmpterminfo
```

Currently that final file location is `~/.terminfo/72/rxvt-unicode-256color` but that may change in the future.

Comment: Just to correct, you have to give `infocmp` the  name of the terminal, not the full path to the terminfo file

Comment: @MaxNoe Ah! Good catch. Correcting